# VBA: Unable to save .doc to .dotm in code

Tags: vba, ms-word

the below function to save the document as ".dotm" returns the error "Command Failed" any ideas?

```
Sub FF()

ChangeFileOpenDirectory "G:\Temp\"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="G:\Temp\yyy.dotm", 
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled

End Sub
```

Thank you

EDIT: I tried the same excat code in C# (not within vba) and it worked, confused!

Comment: Maybe `FileFormat:=wdFormatFlatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled` will do the job.

Comment: If you're not working from the "G" drive you need to change drive first (I think). Try adding `ChDrive "G"` to the top of the procedure.

Comment: Tried both of the above suggestions, same error

Comment: Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415740/word-vba-how-to-save-as-dotm

Comment: Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="G:\Temp\yyy.dotm", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
```

Comment: Same Error for me, are saving as from a ",doc" extension?

Comment: Yes, the "ActiveDocument" you're running the code from is a ".doc" is what i was asking

Comment: Yes, I saved a .doc to a .dotm using only the code in my answer

Comment: Interesting... I have tried the same in a different PC and resulting same error, maybe you have some modified security settings....